# Cannot open php file in localhost

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, htdocs

I have a symfony project (nvs) in my 'htdocs' folder in ubuntu. And my lampp server has been started. Whenever I tried to open the file using 'http://localhost/nvs/index.php' I get the following download dialog (Other symfony projects in the same 'htdocs' folder are opening just fine)

[image]

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Are you sure you have PHP enabled ? Usualy when you request a resource from the server and it haven't specific details how to interpret it it will give you to download. I guess you should enable PHP, or just try to make an restart to the Apache

Comment: all other php files in 'htdocs' are opening fine. Also the phpmyadmin is opening.

Comment: Is the directory allowed to execute, i mean other files in the directory are executing on browser?

Comment: No no files in the directory are executing. How can I allow the directory to execute in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your .htaccess file is correct ?
can you show the contents of that file

remove .php from that if there is any

Comment: it is :AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

Comment: remove .php and check

Comment: Thank you I removed the .htaccess file from the folder and now it works.